# kedro run as a python command instead of command line

Tags: python, kedro

I am getting started with Kedro, so I created the new kedro project for default iris dataset.

I am able to succesfully run it with `kedro run` command. My question now is how do I run it as a python command? From the documentation I read that the command `kedro run`  runs the `src/project-name/run.py`. However, if I run the `run.py` I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'iris_workflow'`. I get the same error if I run the `run` method from `src/project-name/cli.py`.

Everything works fine If I run `kedro run` in terminal.

How do I run `kedro run` from a python script without `subprocess.run()`. If I import the `run.py` or `cli.py` in a script and run it, I get the same error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'iris_workflow'`.

This is the default workflow I created with `kedro new --starter=pandas-iris`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your `src/` folder which is where your project python package lives isn't on your Python path, so if you modify your `PYTHONPATH` first, you'll be able to run `run.py`:

```
~/code/kedro/test-project
test-project ❯ PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$pwd/src python3 src/test_project/run.py
```

To more concretely answer your question, if you wanted to run Kedro from a Python script, you'd do something like this:

```py
import sys

sys.path.append("<path-to-your-project-src")
with KedroSession.create(package_path.name) as session:
    session.run()
```

Comment: Thank you! If I add `src/` folder to path with `sys.path.append`. I get `ValueError: Given configuration path either does not exist or is not a valid directory: ..... iris\src\iris_workflow\conf\base`. It's true because `conf` is not inside `src`, they are at same level. If I had that folder to path then I again get `ModuleNotFoundError`

Comment: It now looks like this: \n

    package_path = Path(\__file\__).resolve().parent \n
    
sys.path.append(str(package_path.parent)) \n

    with KedroSession.create(str(package_path.name)) as session: \n
       
 session.run()

Comment: Make sure that you run your script whilst at the project root, not anywhere else.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to run this from other folder? I want to run kedro project from a script in "python way" from outside the project root. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: That's fine, as long as you move your `conf/` folder to sit alongside your working directory.